# VBA (Excel) Solver for multiple rows + File Saving

Tags: excel, vba, solver

(sorry if this post appeared double)

I have below Solver macro for a specific row (variables in column T, conditions in E and F, all same row). I would like to apply the macro to a range of 5 (or more) rows below and including T5.

Also, I would like the save the workbook in between each completed Solver since the solving is tedious and I fear my PC will crash at some point in the middle of solving a larger range.

Any help much apprecciated!

```
Sub Solver1()
'
' Solver1 Macro
'

'
    SolverOk MaxMinVal:=0, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$T$5", Engine:=3, EngineDesc:= _
        "Evolutionary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$5", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$E$5"
    SolverOk MaxMinVal:=0, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$T$5", Engine:=3, EngineDesc:= _
        "Evolutionary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$T$5", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverOk MaxMinVal:=0, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$T$5", Engine:=3, EngineDesc:= _
        "Evolutionary"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$T$5", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="90"
    SolverOk MaxMinVal:=0, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$T$5", Engine:=3, EngineDesc:= _
        "Evolutionary"
    SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=0, Precision:=0.000000001, Convergence:= _
        0.0000001, StepThru:=False, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1
    SolverOptions PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.000075, _
        Multistart:=False, RequireBounds:=True, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
        IntTolerance:=1, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
    SolverOk MaxMinVal:=0, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$T$5", Engine:=3, EngineDesc:= _
        "Evolutionary"
    SolverOk MaxMinVal:=0, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$T$5", Engine:=3, EngineDesc:= _
        "Evolutionary"
    SolverSolve
End Sub
```

Comment: If you know what solver does, better not use it. Write a macro to do the same directly to variables/arrays and save up over 90% of the time.

Comment: Please understand that I have to use a Solver (according to stackoverflow replies on my previous post, due to the massive circular referencing etc.). I already made another post about this here and the conclusion was that Solver is the way to go for me (and it works... I have no experience to code myself, so I would like to keep using that which is working). Is there a way that what I am asking to do can be achieved?

Comment: Solver is no magic... it is more like brute force. And also directly to the sheet which is pretty slow to begin with. If you can tell me what you have, want and in which relationship the values are, I'm sure a fast solution should not be the big deal ;)

Comment: The fast solution for doing it for multiple rows would be to run a loop like `For i = 5 to 8` and then change parts like `CellRef:="$F$5"` simply to `CellRef:="$F$" & i`... and saving the workbook via vba is easy to find on this site or any search engine. (Depends a bit on what you like to have)

Comment: I attached my excel file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3dbXIMNWGfSWlROeXA3TW5rV1U    including macro. I am worried though that you will just tell me that this is all a big mess.... which it might be but I want to make it work....

Comment: I will have a look at it as soon as possible.

Comment: Any help very very much appreciated, Danke!

Comment: There is an other workbook where it pulls a lot of values from... Just to make some *use able* calculations, I need the values from sheet `CCR` columns `S` & `Z` and sheet `DR Step1` columns `J` & `P`. Can you provide a wb holding this sheets/values?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, please find the values as below: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3dbXIMNWGfSakNCVGd0dk5ZdjA

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3dbXIMNWGfSZjQ1aE1LczJiTE0

Comment: The google drive file is not public... Try somthing like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36117527/store-solver-result-with-for-and-next-loop-in-excel/36117918#36117918 adding a line to save the file after each loop:
`ActiveWorkbook.Save`
HTH

Comment: Very sorry for my mistake, I have re-uploaded it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3dbXIMNWGfSdEdrdnk2U2JJVG8/view?usp=sharing.    Thank you for having checked it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few (potential) problems with what you posted that need to be corrected before providing a solution for looping.

1. You have not specified SetCell in your call to SolverOK. The [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839427.aspx) indicates SetCell is optional, but Solver requires "something" to be the objective. If you have already specified "Set Objective" in the dialog box manually, the code may work. Or it may not, depending on innumerable possible events. The worksheet you posted is not publicly available, so we have no way of knowing what your objective cell is.
2. You have specified `MaxMinVal:=0`. This is an invalid specification. The [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839427.aspx) indicates 1=Maximize, 2=Minimize, 3=Match a specific value. I'm going to assume you meant `MaxMinVal"=1` to maximize the objective.
3. You have specified `ValueOf:=0`. This specification is only required if `MaxMinVal:=3` is specified (e.g. Match a specific value). Since I am assuming you intended to maximize the objective, the ValueOf specification is not required.
4. You have specified both `Engine:=3` and `EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"`. Although, when you record a macro, both of these parameters are provided, specifying them both is redundant and can lead to an inconsistent spec. If they are specified inconsistently, then the SolverOK call fails without generating an error. I would specify only `Engine:=3`.
5. You have multiple calls to SolverOK. This is a remnant of the code generated when recording a macro. Only one SolverOK call is required.
6. You have multiple SolverAdd calls for constraints. This is OK, but you need to do something to manage these through the looping activity. If you don't remove the constraints, they will accumulate. This is not bad if you only have a couple of SolverSolve calls to make, but can cause problems if you have many to make.

In the code below, in addition to addressing the items above, I have also done the following ...

1. Use SolverReset to clear all solver specifications. I have normally advocated to avoid using SolverReset as it interacts with SolverSolve, when called before SolverSolve, to leave the Calculation mode of Excel in Manual. However, it turns out if you call SolverReset after SolverSolve, you get the same reset action, but the calculation mode is not "messed" with.
2. Use ActiveWorkbook.Save to save the workbook after each solve. Make sure the workbook has already been saved as a macro enabled workbook.
3. Use the method Dirk suggested in the comments for building the strings for addresses required by Solver. There are other methods, but this method works well in this case. Although the MS documentation shows Ranges can be provided to the Solver routines, this does not always work.

In order to use the code below, you will need to:

- Change `SetCell:="$U$" & iLoop` to represent the objective cell in your workbook.
- Validate that you want to maximize the objective. Otherwise, change `MaxMinVal:=1` to the appropriate value. If you set `MaxMinVal:=3`, then you will need to re-insert `ValueOf`.

The code ...

```
Sub Solver2()
'
Dim iLoop As Long
    For iLoop = 5 To 9
        SolverOk SetCell:="$U$" & iLoop, MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:="$T$" & iLoop, Engine:=3
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$F$" & iLoop, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$E$" & iLoop
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$T$" & iLoop, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$T$" & iLoop, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="90"
        SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=0, Precision:=0.000000001, Convergence:= _
            0.0000001, StepThru:=False, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1
        SolverOptions PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.000075, _
            Multistart:=False, RequireBounds:=True, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
            IntTolerance:=1, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        SolverReset
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Next iLoop
End Sub
```

---

**Edit - based on examining worksheet layout**

The way the worksheet is laid out, your objective cell is in Column F and the target for the objective is in Column E. Column U is just a boolean calculation to determine if the answer is "close enough". The code below is a better way to represent this in Solver. *Also, I would consider using GRG Nonlinear*

```
Dim iLoop As Long
    For iLoop = 4 To 9
        SolverOk SetCell:="$F$" & iLoop, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="$E$" & iLoop, ByChange:="$T$" & iLoop, Engine:=3
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$T$" & iLoop, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:="$T$" & iLoop, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="90"
        SolverOptions MaxTime:=0, Iterations:=0, Precision:=0.0000001, Convergence:= _
            0.00001, StepThru:=False, Scaling:=True, AssumeNonNeg:=True, Derivatives:=1
        SolverOptions PopulationSize:=100, RandomSeed:=0, MutationRate:=0.0075, _
            Multistart:=False, RequireBounds:=True, MaxSubproblems:=0, MaxIntegerSols:=0, _
            IntTolerance:=1, SolveWithout:=False, MaxTimeNoImp:=30
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
        SolverReset
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Next iLoop
End Sub
```

Comment: First of, super apprecciate your hard work! I have to admit that I understand max. half of this, so I am going back to my textbook : )) I have input your code and it computes (sometimes), but mostly gets stuck at "setting up problem....99% Done". I have the feeling that my whole sheet isn't really working as I want it to. I have uploaded the whole workbook below: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3dbXIMNWGfSdEdrdnk2U2JJVG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Michu1 - You formula is too complex for me to diagnose, but your workbook is full of circular references. You need to eliminate circular references this in order for solver to work. For example: D6 has Q6 as input, Q6 has M6 as input, M6 has K6 as input, K6 has D6 as input.

Comment: @Michu1 - You have several places where your equations are trying to SQRT a negative number. You need to protect your equations from generating errors. (like divide by 0, sqrt of negative, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, But I was pretty busy :(

I also wasn't able to simplify your calculations, however, this macro may be much more what you desire (no solver, still the use of the worksheet)

```
Sub No_Solver_Solve()
  Dim valR As Double, valO As Double, valT As Double, oBool As Boolean, i As Long, holder As String

  Dim UVal As Long, LVal As Long, SVal As Double, Trow As Long, BRow As Long, MaxDiff As Double

  UVal = 150      'upper limit
  LVal = 0        'lower limit
  SVal = 10       'initial stepping
  MaxDiff = 0.001 'max difference from target value

  Trow = 5 'top row
  BRow = 25 'bottom row

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

  For i = Trow To BRow
    valR = SVal
    Range("T" & i) = UVal
    holder = Range("D" & i).Formula
    Range("D" & i).Value = 0
    Calculate
    Range("D" & i).Formula = holder
    Calculate

      'get first non-error value
    While IsError(Range("U" & i)) And Range("T" & i) >= LVal
      Range("T" & i) = Range("T" & i) - SVal
      Rows(i).Calculate
      Rows(i).Calculate
    Wend

      'if only errors are found
    If Range("T" & i) < LVal Then
      MsgBox "No valid value found for row " & i & "!"
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      Exit Sub
    End If

      'jump over peak
    valO = (Range("E" & i) - Range("F" & i))
    oBool = (valO >= 0)
    valT = Range("T" & i)
    If valT = LVal Then valR = -valR

    While (oBool And ((Range("E" & i) - Range("F" & i)) > 0)) Or (Not oBool And ((Range("E" & i) - Range("F" & i)) < 0))

      Range("T" & i) = Range("T" & i) - valR
      Rows(i).Calculate

        'if step ends in error (smaller step)
      If IsError(Range("F" & i)) Then
        Range("T" & i) = Range("T" & i) + valR
        valR = valR / 2
        Rows(i).Calculate

        'peak outside of range
      ElseIf (valT = LVal Or valT = UVal) And (oBool And (valO < (Range("E" & i) - Range("F" & i)))) Or (Not oBool And (valO > (Range("E" & i) - Range("F" & i)))) Then
        MsgBox "Peak out of range for row " & i & "!"
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Exit Sub

        'deactivate for later runs
      Else
        If valT = LVal Or valT = UVal Then
          If LVal <> 0 And UVal <> 0 Then
            valT = 0
          ElseIf LVal <> 1 And UVal <> 1 Then
            valT = 1
          Else
            valT = 2
          End If
        End If
      End If

    Wend

       'run for peak
    While Abs(Range("E" & i) - Range("F" & i)) > MaxDiff
      valR = valR / 2
      oBool = ((Range("E" & i) - Range("F" & i)) > 0)
      Range("T" & i) = Range("T" & i) + valR
      Rows(i).Calculate
      Rows(i).Calculate
      If oBool = ((Range("E" & i) - Range("F" & i)) < 0) Then valR = -valR
    Wend
  Next

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

For me, it took ~1.5 seconds to run row 5 to 9 (and row 10 would be 105 which is out of range). Please run the code row by row to know what happens and how it works and if something is not clear, just ask. ;)

However, sometimes there is some "hopping". This means that values will be change every time it is recalculated. This way a workable solution may go over your "round" after some iterations and will be wrong later on. For this reason I removed the `ROUND` from the formulas in column F. (Still took ~1.5 sec for all rows down to 25.)

This also should kill your errors (as far as I can see, there is no limit for going to positive). At the other hand, it may fail if the step is to big and the peak is pretty close to the max/min values. (this way you should increase them a bit to be sure)